# Sort data file based on a separate key file

Tags: sorting, gnu-coreutils, gnu-sort

1. We have 2 files: `data.txt` and `keys.txt`.
2. `data.txt` is some proper unicode text with `N` lines.
3. `keys.txt` is a list of newline-separated integers, `N` lines.
4. Output a file `sorted.txt` where the lines in `data.txt` are sorted according to `keys.txt` *without* writing an intermediate file `paste -d',' keys.txt data.txt`.

I need to use this for large files (hundreds of GB) on machines with 16-32 GB of memory.

My first attempt was to do it in Python, which is a bit slow. It's simple enough, so we discussed doing it in C++. But I'd prefer if it uses readily available tools so there's no installation needed. This could well be impossible to do efficiently with GNU or Unix tools, but I don't know enough there to make a claim.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this without buffering to a file. For performance, I guess calibrating `sort --buffer-size` would be the first move, and perhaps using `parallel` to sort in chunks the second.

```
paste keys.txt data.txt | sort -n -k1 | cut -f2-
```

Comment: How does `sort` sort here when the data isn't all there yet without writing it? Chunking by `--buffer-size`?